# Align decimal numbers with different digital numbers

Tags: siunitx, threeparttable, dcolumn, decimal-number

I am trying to create the following table, and I have two problems regarding this table:

1- The numbers before and after the "." in the table are different numbers. I am trying to use the code`{l*{2}{S[table-format = 3.1]}}` to align digital numbers, but it failed. How can I achieve the alignment of decimal numbers for such a table？(Could you please give a comment to explain the codes?)

2- Is there any way to control the width for each column in the table as well? I tried c{2cm} and the error is shown as "illegal characteristics."

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering      
    \caption{The results on the datasets} 
    \begin{tabular} 
    {c|c|c|c|c}
        \hline            
        {Methodology}  &  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Data 1}   &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Data 2}  \\  \cline{2-5}
        & mean $\pm$ std & p\_value & mean$\pm$ std &  p\_value    \\  \hline
    method 1 &   $1700.5\pm 200.91$  & $0.0\%$  & $-10000.2\pm800.0$ & $0.0\%$     \\ 
        method 2 &   $300.8\pm 100.0$  & $0.5\%$ & $-10002.18\pm 800.5$  & $0.0\%$   \\    
         method 3 &   $-100.5\pm 200.2$ & $10.5\%$  & $-8006.8\pm 899.8$  & $0.0\%$     \\          Method 4 &  $553.83 \pm 102.2$ & $0.1\%$  & $-20090.8\pm 300.1$  & $0.0\%$    \\   
            
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm on mobile so I can't test, but with siunitx, you have to wrap non-numbers with { }, excluding the multicolumn row.

Comment: The `\caption` table should *always* be part of the `threeparttable` environment. Since your example does not do that and doesn't contain a `tablenotes` environment either, what's the purpose of encasing the `tabular` environment in a `threeparttable` environment?

Comment: @Mico Thanks. I have modified the question and posted a new one.  ```threeparttable``` is for ```tablenotes```, but I removed that part in the sample code, which has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 6):

- To typeset a column of numbers with associated separate uncertainties, you may use the `siunitx` package, set the package option `separate-uncertainty`, remove the `$` inline math initiators and terminators, and set the column type to (say) `S[table-format=-3.2(3.2)]`.
- To make a column centered and have a fixed width of (say) 2 cm, load the `array` package (aside: the `array` package is very useful, and hence many other packages load the `array` package automatically), and change `c` to `w{c}{2cm}`.

[image]

Observe that I also chose the give the table a more open "look" by omitting all vertical lines and by replacing `\hline` and `\cline` with the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,booktabs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[separate-uncertainty,group-minimum-digits=4]{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering      
    \caption{Summary statistics for datasets\strut} 
    \begin{tabular}{@{} l S[table-format=-3.2(3.2)] S
                          S[table-format=-5.2(3.2)] S @{}}
    \toprule            
    Methodology & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Data 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Data 2}  \\  
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
    & {mean $\pm$ std} & {p\_value} & {mean$\pm$ std} &  {p\_value} \\ 
    \midrule
    method 1 &  1700.5\pm 200.91 &  0.0\% & -10000.2 \pm 800.0 & 0.0\%     \\ 
    method 2 &   300.8\pm 100.0  &  0.5\% & -10002.18\pm 800.5 & 0.0\%   \\    
    method 3 &  -100.5\pm 200.2  & 10.5\% &  -8006.8 \pm 899.8 & 0.0\%     \\  
    method 4 &  553.83 \pm 102.2 & 0.1\%  & -20090.8 \pm 300.1 & 0.0\%    \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear Mico, I am still waiting for Overleaf's reply. I add a new table that needs to align decimal numbers. At the same time, I want R^2 and Observations to be in the center (not align). Could you please also help with this? Thanks. @Mico

Comment: @Lernst - Substantially new queries should be posted as new answers, not as augmentations to earlier queries.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering      
    \caption{The results on the datasets} 
    \sisetup{separate-uncertainty, table-column-width=3.25cm}
    \begin{tabular} 
    {c|S[table-format=-3.2(3.2)]|S[table-format=2.1]|S[table-format=-5.2(3.2)]|S[table-format=1.1]|}
        \hline            
        {Methodology}  &  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Data 1}   &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Data 2}  \\  \cline{2-5}
        & {\phantom{\num{-100.50}}\llap{mean} $\pm$ \rlap{std}\phantom{\num{200.91}}} & {p\_value (\%)} & {\phantom{\num{-10002.18}}\llap{mean} $\pm$ \rlap{std}\phantom{\num{800.50}}} & { p\_value (\%)}    \\  \hline
       method 1 &   1700.50(20091) & 0.0  & -10000.2(8000) & 0.0    \\ 
       method 2 &   300.8(1000)  & 0.5 & -10002.18(80050)  & 0.0   \\    
       method 3 &   -100.5(2002) & 10.5  & -8006.8(8998)  & 0.0     \\          
       Method 4 &  553.83(1022) & 0.1  & -20090.8(3001) & 0.0    \\   
            
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
    \centering      
    \caption{The results on the datasets} 
    \sisetup{separate-uncertainty}
    \begin{tabular} 
    {cS[table-format=-3.2(3.2)]S[table-format=2.1]S[table-format=-5.2(3.2)]S[table-format=1.1]}
        \toprule            
        {Methodology}  &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Data 1}   &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Data 2}  \\  \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
        & {\phantom{\num{-100.50}}\llap{mean} $\pm$ \rlap{std}\phantom{\num{200.91}}} & {p\_value (\%)} & {\phantom{\num{-10002.18}}\llap{mean} $\pm$ \rlap{std}\phantom{\num{800.50}}} & { p\_value (\%)}    \\ 
        \midrule
       method 1 &   1700.50(20091) & 0.0  & -10000.2(8000) & 0.0    \\ 
       method 2 &   300.8(1000)  & 0.5 & -10002.18(80050)  & 0.0   \\    
       method 3 &   -100.5(2002) & 10.5  & -8006.8(8998)  & 0.0     \\          
       Method 4 &  553.83(1022) & 0.1  & -20090.8(3001) & 0.0    \\   
       \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Quick question: Is there an advantage (maybe in terms of additional generality?) to changing the cell contents from `1700.5\pm 200.91` to `1700.50(20091)`, `300.8\pm 100.0` to `300.8(1000)`, etc.?

Comment: Thank you so much for both of you！ One quick question, I copied your codes to overleaf, but the latex codes show errors:  "package siunitx error: invalid uncertainty in numerical input '-3.2 (3.2)' also for '-5.2 (3.2)'. The table can be created, but I lost all the numbers after $pm$... What's the issue?

Comment: @Lernst - For people who maintain their own TeX distributions, the `siunitx` package recently received a major upgrade and many additional capabilities. It may be the case that the default version of `siunitx` that's installed on Overleaf has not yet received the latest upgrades. All I can suggest is that you contact the Overleaf Helpdesk -- I hear their LaTeX support staff are top-notch! -- and ask them for assistance. They should be able to diagnose the situation in detail and, if need be, give you access to a more recent version of `siunitx` on a one-off basis.

Comment: @Mico: I don't know of any advantages of `1700.50(20091)` over `1700.5\pm 200.91`. It's just the input syntay I'm more used to and I keep forgetting that `1700.5\pm 200.91` is also interpretable by `siunitx`.

Comment: @Mico Thank you for your reply. I have contacted the Overleaf helpdesk and let's see what's the issue.